# Add Thickness to faces

Tags: javascript, three.js

i create walls by creating faces with some points i have.
The creation of the walls does work without an issue.
Now i want to add some thickness to my walls but iam not quite sure how to.

here is my code for creating my walls:

```
makeWall(start, end) {

let v1 = this.helpers.toVec3(start); //0

let v2 = this.helpers.toVec3(end);  //1

let v3 = v2.clone(); //2
v3.y = this.wallHeight;

let v4 = v1.clone(); //3
v4.y = this.wallHeight;


let points = [ v1.clone(), v2.clone(), v3.clone(), v4.clone() ]; 

console.log("Points", points )

let mesh:THREE.Mesh;
let geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

let label: THREE.Sprite;
let walldirection;

geometry.vertices = [v1, v2, v3, v4];
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 3));

geometry = this.helpers.assignUVs(geometry);

mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, this.wallMaterial);
...
}
```

at the end the walls form a closed Room together.
For Example the points are:

```
(4) [p, p, p, p]
0: p {x: 200, y: 0, z: -500}
1: p {x: 200, y: 0, z: 300}
2: p {x: 200, y: 277, z: 300}
3: p {x: 200, y: 277, z: -500}
length: 4
```

thanks for looking into it

Update//
i think iam on the right track now.
i added 4 more points with a offset and created faces for them but there is still something wrong. Probably the Faces are wrong ?

```
  let v1ex = v1.clone(); // 4
    v1ex.x = v1ex.x - 10;

    let v2ex = v2.clone(); // 5 
    v2ex.x = v1ex.x + 10;

    let v3ex = v3.clone(); // 6 
    v3ex.x = v3ex.x + 10;

    let v4ex = v4.clone();  // 7 
    v4ex.x = v4ex.x - 10;

    let points = [ v1.clone(), v2.clone(), v3.clone(), v4.clone() , v1ex , v2ex , v3ex , v4ex ]; 

    let mesh:THREE.Mesh;
    let geometry = new THREE.Geometry( );

    let label: THREE.Sprite;
    let walldirection;

    geometry.vertices = [v1, v2, v3, v4 , v1ex , v2ex , v3ex , v4ex];

    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3( 0 , 1 , 2 ) );
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3( 0 , 2 , 3 ) );

    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3( 4 , 5 , 6 ) );
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3( 4 , 6 , 7 ) );

    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3( 7 , 3 , 6 ) );
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3( 7 , 3 , 2 ) );

    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3( 0 , 5 , 1 ) );
    geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3( 0 , 5 , 4 ) );
```

Comment: Why not to use meshes of thin `THREE.BoxGeometry()`/`THREE.BoxBufferGeometry()`?

Comment: because i dont know how to make a BoxGeometry that starts at my start point and ends at my end point tbh :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a concept of how you can do it, using a mesh with thin `THREE.BoxGeometry()`:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 3, 5).setLength(10);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var pointStart = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 3);
var pointEnd = new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, -3);
var height = 4;
var thickness = 0.1;

var boxW = pointEnd.clone().sub(pointStart).length();
var boxH = height;
var boxD = thickness;

var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxW, boxH, boxD);
boxGeometry.translate(boxW * 0.5, boxH * 0.5, 0);
boxGeometry.rotateY(-Math.PI * 0.5);
var wall = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  wireframe: true
}));
wall.position.copy(pointStart);
wall.lookAt(pointEnd);
scene.add(wall);

addPoint(pointStart, "green");
addPoint(pointEnd, "yellow");

function addPoint(position, color) {
  let p = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.125, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: color
  }));
  p.position.copy(position);
  scene.add(p);
}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/92/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well. I still have some issues but those are from other parts of my code. But you could maybe help me with another problem. I had the Material side set to backside so that the wall on the front doesnt show from one side. Now that doesnt happen and the wall is always visible on every angle. But if i understand right that should not have changed at all ?

Comment: @EnginO You're welcome :) About your question. I didn't get, do you keep using `side: THREE.BackSide`? Just an advice: create a new question here, or ask about it at the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/), as it's out of the scope of the current question :).

Comment: Its just a "small" question so i didnt want to create a new one. Yes the wallmaterial is set on side:Backside. But it kind of does only apply to the outer side of the new wall, the inner side is always visible. Sorry for my bad english, thats why i cant explain it perfectly :). But again, thank you for your answer :) learned a lot from it and have other uses for it!

Comment: @EnginO English is not my native language too :) I can't realize, why do you use `THREE.BackSide` for the wall material. Use `THREE.FrontSide` instead or simply remove `side` parameter, thus the material will use its default value - `THREE.FrontSide`.

Comment: because it now looks like this with FrontSide ( https://imgur.com/vV9cATU ) but it should look like this with BackSide ( https://imgur.com/lFE6gOq )

Comment: @EnginO Ah, I think I got what you mean. You want the same behaviour, like if the walls of the room were simple planes with `THREE.BackSide`. Come to the forum with this question, I'll try to help you there :)

Comment: allright :) opened a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50372250/boxgeometry-sides